# List values which occur between 2 strings

Tags: powershell

I have a file which basically includes content like:

```
<INCOND NAME="DWH_YDWB-Start" ODATE="STAT" AND_OR="AND" />
<INCOND NAME="BBYSICH01.NR" ODATE="ODAT" AND_OR="AND" />
<INCOND NAME="YDWB_AB-Start" ODATE="STAT" AND_OR="AND" />
<ON CODE="NOTOK" STMT="*">
<DOSYSOUT OPTION="Copy" 
  PAR="\\$CTMSERVER$\Sysout\%%ODATE._%%JOBNAME._#%%RUNCOUNT..txt" />
</ON>
```

I just want to list all the Values of the INCONDs, who start with BBY - which would be 'BBYSICH01.NR'

So i started with:

```
get-content 'C:\Temp\test.xml' -ReadCount 1000 | 
 foreach { $_ -match 'INCOND NAME=\"BBY' }
```

Does list all the lines i want to have, but i just need the value 'BBYSICH01.NR' listed, not the whole line and i completely fail at this point.
Tried different ways, but always ended up in a desaster.

Is there any simple way to extract just this value 'BBYSICH01.NR'?

Thanks in advance
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the the Select-String cmdlet and use a regex to extract your text like so:

```
Select-String yourfile.txt -Pattern '(?<=<INCOND NAME=")BBY\w+\.\w+' | Select -ExpandProperty Matches | Select -ExpandProperty Value
```

Should be a lot faster than using Get-Content

Comment: dave, thanks a lot!
can you recommend any page where i can learn more about regex? 
i don't understand the pattern entirely.

Comment: One of my favorites is [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)